# SAS Creating entries by group

Tags: arrays, sas, sequence

I have an array that I want to add years and months sequentially to using a SAS program:

```
Original:
ID
1
2
3


End result:
ID  YEAR; MONTH
1   2014 11
1   2014 12
1   2015 1
1   2015 2
1   2015 3
2   2014 11
2   2014 12
2   2015 1
2   2015 2
2   2015 3
3   2014 11
3   2014 12
3   2015 1
3   2015 2
3   2015 3
```

I also need to set the upper lower limits for the years and months I want to add to the table.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Good morning, as @Anton stated you should show what you have already tried, it helps us understand the logic you are trying to take without doing all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, I'm taking a bit of a guess on what you're looking for. From what you're asking, I'd recommned using a data step to loop through your original data, outputing multiple rows for each line in the original data.

This uses `intnx` to advance to the next month ([intnx documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212700.htm))

```
*Enter start and end date here;
%Let startdt = '01NOV2014'd;
%Let enddt = '01MAR2015'd;

data want (drop=_date);
    set original;

    *Create multiple records for each observation in 'original'- one for each month;
    _date = &startdt;
    DO UNTIL (_date > &enddt);
        year = year(_date);
        month = month(_date);
        output;

        *Advance to next month;
        _date = intnx('month', _date, 1, 'beginning');
    END;
run;
```